# What's better, isset or not?

Tags: php, isset

Is there any speed difference between

```
if (isset($_POST['var']))
```

or

```
if ($_POST['var'])
```

And which is better or are they the same?

Comment: Clearly, it takes longer to type isset() :/

Comment: Just wondered if there was any real reason why it would be needed in this case. I guess not

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It is a good practice to use `isset` for the following reasons:

- If `$_POST['var']` is an empty string or `"0"`, `isset` will still detect that the variable exists.
- Not using isset will generate a notice.

Answer (score 14):

They aren't the same. Consider a notional array:

```
$arr = array(
  'a' => false,
  'b' => 0,
  'c' => '',
  'd' => array(),
  'e' => null,
  'f' => 0.0,
);
```

Assuming `$x` is one of those keys ('a' to 'f') and the key 'g' which isn't there it works like this:

- `$arr[$x]` is `false` for all keys a to g;
- `isset($arr[$x])` is `true` for keys a, b, c, d and f but `false` for e and g; and
- `array_key_exists($x, $arr)` is `true` for all keys a to f, `false` for g.

I suggest you look at [PHP's type juggling](http://au.php.net/language.types.type-juggling), specifically conversion to booleans.

Lastly, what you're doing is called [micro-optimization](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/archives/000185.html). Never choose which one of those by whichever is perceived to be faster. Whichever is faster is so negligible in difference that it should **never** be a factor even if you could reliably determine which is faster (which I'm not sure you could to any statistically significant level).

Comment: cletus is right - one SQL query will be a thousand times slower than a thousand isset checks. It's also worth noting that if($arr['g']) will generate an E_NOTICE "Undefined variable".

Answer (score 4):

`isset` tests that the variable has any value, while the if tests the value of the variable.

For example:

```
// $_POST['var'] == 'false' (the string false)
if (isset($_POST['var'])) {
    // Will enter this if
}
if ($_POST['var']) {
    // Won't enter this one
}
```

The big problem is that the equivalency of the two expressions depends on the value of the variable you are checking, so you can't make assumptions.

Comment: I have a feeling you need a little correction on the first line. isset doesn't "test that the variable has any value" it tests if it has been instantiated/created `$a = ''; isset($a);` will evaluate to true.

Answer (score 1):

In strict PHP, you need to check if a variable is set before using it.

```
error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT);
```

What you are doing here

if($var)

Isn't checking if the value is set. So Strict PHP will generate a notice for unset variables. (this happens a lot with arrays)

Also in strict PHP (just an FYI for you or others), using an unset var as an argument in a function will throw a notice and you can't check isset() within the function to avoid that.

Comment: This is not completely correct.  E_STRICT has nothing to do with a notice being thrown in this case.  Even if E_STRICT is off, a notice is still thrown.

Comment: You mean in code or log file? Because you need to enable E_STRICT in the php.ini for it to be thrown (pre PHP 6)

Answer (score 0):

Just repeating what others said, if you execute:

```
if($variable)
```

and $variable is **not** set, you'll get a notice error. Plus..

```
$var = 0;
if($variable) {
    //This code will never run, because $var is false
}
```

but using isset would return true in this case.