# Why do I need the isset() function in php?

Tags: php, post, if-statement, isset

I am trying to understand the difference between this:

```
if (isset($_POST['Submit'])) { 
  //do something
}
```

and

```
if ($_POST['Submit']) { 
  //do something
}
```

It seems to me that if the $_POST['Submit'] variable is true, then it is set. Why would I need the isset() function in this case?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Because

```
$a = array("x" => "0");

if ($a["x"])
  echo "This branch is not executed";

if (isset($a["x"]))
  echo "But this will";
```

(See also http://hk.php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php and http://hk.php.net/manual/en/language.types.boolean.php#language.types.boolean.casting)

Comment: so should I just always use the isset function in cases like these?

Comment: Trying to access `$a["x"]` will also raise an `E_Notice` when there is no key `x` defined inside `$a`. Checking with `isset` or `array_key_exists` can avoid this.

Comment: @Chris: Always use `isset` to check the *existence* of a certain variable.

Comment: Also the isset function prevents a warning in case the variable is not set. If you do this if ($bla) and there is no bla, php will issue a warning saying that there is no $bla variable

Answer (score 4):

isset will return TRUE if it exists and is not NULL otherwise it is FALSE.

Answer (score 3):

You basically want to check if the $_POST[] variable has been submitted at all, regardless of value. If you do not use isset(), certain submissions like `submit=0` will fail.

Answer (score 1):

In your 2nd example, PHP will issue a notice (on `E_NOTICE` or stricter) if that key is not set for `$_POST`.

Also see [this question on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/844410/whats-better-isset-or-not).

Answer (score 0):

The code

```
if($_POST['Submit'])
{
//some code
}
```

will not work in WAMP (works on xampp)
on WAMP you will have to use

```
if (isset($_POST['Submit'])) { 
  //do something
}
```

try it. :)

Comment: This sounds more like default error handling setup then an operating system.

Answer (score 0):

if user do not enter a value so $_post[] return NULL that we say in the description of isset:"

isset will return TRUE if it exists and is not NULL otherwise it is FALSE.,but in here isset return the true
"