# if and isset which one to use

Tags: php, php-5.3

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why do I need the isset() function in php?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2460290/why-do-i-need-the-isset-function-in-php)

whats the difference if I say

```
if($value){}
```

vs

```
if (isset($value)){}
```

I had been asked to change if($value) to isset($value)

thanks

Comment: You probably want `isset($value) && ((bool) $value)`, which checks if it's set and if it evaluates to `true`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP generates a warning (Undefined variable) when you access an undefined variable using `if ($value)`

Use `if (isset($value))` to test if a variable has been declared.

Use `if ($value)` if you know the variable has been declared, and you want to evaluate the contents as boolean.

Answer (score 1):

```
$value = "";
$value = 0;
var $value;
```

In the above cases, `$value` will return `false` because the values are considered null. However, they are considered set by PHP and therefore `isset($value)` will return `true` in these cases.

Enjoy!

Comment: that's clear. If value is set to `false` or `null`, `isset` will return true.

Answer (score 1):

```
    if( $value ) {}
```

would return false if the variable contained a false value such as 0 or false

```
    if( isset( $value ) ) {}
```

would return true if the variable has been initialized with any value including 0 or false

Answer (score 1):

well, to start, `if($value){}` will raise a E_NOTICE warning if the variable isnt set.

besides that, `if($value){}`

will evaluate if $value is trutty or falsy(IE, it evaluates to false or true).

while `if(isset($value)){}`

will see if the variable its defined somewhere, not caring for its content

Comment: Actually, it's an `E_NOTICE`.