# PHP: how to use sessions/cookies inside iframe with different domain name?

Tags: php, cookies, iframe, session-cookies

I got that simple script on **server1**

```
<iframe src="https://server2/index.php" width=800 height=800>
```

and on **server2**

index.php

```
    <?php session_start();
    $_SESSION['test'] = 'test';
    ?>
   <body>
         <a href="index2.php">Go !</a>
   </body>
```

index2.php

```
<?php session_start();
print_r($_SESSION);
```

and... result is empty:

Is there a 'simple' way to allow sessions on iframes ?
I tried with

ini_set("session.use_cookies","0");

Same issue. The only way I found so far is to pass the sessionid parameter between pages which is very complex (I have to rewritten many pages, change a lot of scripts, change ajax calls..)

Is there a quicker round around for that ?

Comment: Did you try https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8957769/php-session-iframe ? It seems relevant.

Comment: yes I did and did not work. This "issue" is very recent. These are new 3rd party cookies policy